# String and Int concatenation doesn't render in HTML class attribute

Tags: php, html, concatenation, bbcode

I'm extending [HTML_BBCodeParser2](http://pear.php.net/package/HTML_BBCodeParser2/). It parses input BBCode and translates to HTML. The offending function is set up like so:

```
var $_definedTags = array(
  'color' => array( 'htmlopen'  => 'span',
                  'htmlclose' => 'span',
                  'allowed'   => 'all',
                  'attributes'=> array('color' =>'style=%2$scolor:%1$s%2$s')),

  'size' => array( 'htmlopen'  => 'span',
                 'htmlclose' => 'span',
                 'allowed'   => 'all',
                 'attributes'=> array('size' =>'class=%2$ssize%1$s%2$s'))
    );
```

The first parse, 'color', works correctly. If I input

> [color=blue]Color me Blue![/color]

the output will be

```
<span style="color:blue">Color me Blue!</span>
```

and render correctly.

For 'size', I want to modify the class attribute. I input the following:

> [size=4]Resize Me![/size]

The output of this is simply the span tag with no attribute:

```
<span>Resize me!</span>
```

However, if I put anything in that cannot be recognized as anything else but as a string, the HTML is displayed correctly:

> [size=4.]Resize Me![/size]

Outputs:

```
<span class="size4.">Resize me!</span>
```

Why is this the case?